Exporting GeoPackage to shapefile
I have a GeoPackage layer with point features containing some important attributes. When I try to export this layer into a shapefile format the point features are exported but all of the attributes are lost.

How can I export the layer to shapefile format and retain the attributes?
I export to shapefile by selecting the point features I want to convert->right click->export ->save selected features as->choose esri shapefile format and selected attributes->export.
What I get is a shapefile layer with the selected features but all the field names of the shapefile change to numbers and their values appear as null


I select the point features I want to export from the gpkg layer.  Right click on the layer->export ->save selected features as. I chose esri shapefile as format and also select the attribute fields that I would like to export.

What do you mean by all of the attributes are lost ? do you get all row and all column but with empty attribute  or you don't get any column or you don't get any row or ...

Can you share a sample file giving this problem?

Your export procedure as described in comment (you should rather edit your question to add this) sound right and should give you the full data (minus the shapefile limitations regarding field name length, DateTime data type and Null value handling…) You need to give more information to determine what went wrong

None of the names on the shapefile are dBase-conformant (Unique 10 characters UPPERCASE -- "ID" is reserved for the fid). As a rule, shapefile should not be an output format from any database, since names are corrupted, types are changed, NULLs and datetime are lost, and text fields truncated at 254 bytes.
